In Azure Functions in Python. Setting SessionID when publishing message to Azure Service Bus
I drafted an Azure Function in Python, model V2.
I have successfully published a message into a topic.
Now I would like to set a SessionID for a published message, but can not figure out how. How do I publish a message with a SessionId?
My attempt with JSON in "my_json_string" variable was not recognized by Azure.


import logging
import azure.functions as func
from datetime import datetime
import json


app = func.FunctionApp()

# vs output into queue for python
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python


@app.route(route="http_trigger_topic", auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)
@app.service_bus_topic_output(arg_name="message",
                              connection="ServiceBusConnection",
                              topic_name="alfdevapi6topic")
def http_trigger_topic(req: func.HttpRequest, message: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    myMessage = "Hi alf this is my message via the queue to you."
    logging.info(myMessage)
    
    input_msg = req.params.get('message')

    now = datetime.now()
    print("now =", now)

    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    my_json_string = f"""
    {{
        "body": "{myMessage}",
        "customProperties": {{
            "messagenumber": 0,
            "timePublish": "{now}",
        }},
        "brokerProperties": {{
            "SessionId": "1"
        }}
    }}
    """


    message.set(my_json_string)


    return func.HttpResponse(
        "This function should process queue messages.",
        status_code=200
    )




Seems that there is an open issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/115073

I do agree  with  @Skip that func.Out cannot send the message with session id.
But alternatively you can use below code using SDK:
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage

app = func.FunctionApp()
@app.service_bus_topic_trigger(arg_name="azservicebus", subscription_name="mysubscription", topic_name="mysbtopic",
                               connection="sbfiltersid_SERVICEBUS") 
def servicebus_topic_trigger(azservicebus: func.ServiceBusMessage):
    logging.info('Python ServiceBus Topic trigger processed a message: %s',
                azservicebus.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
    rith_con = "Endpoint=sb://sbfiltersid.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=MT5eFCEndpoint=sb://sbfiltersid.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=MT5eFCUG+Ng="
    rith_qn = "rithwik"
    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(rith_con)
    rith_sen = servicebus_client.get_queue_sender(rith_qn)
    rith_msg = ServiceBusMessage("Hello Rithwik Bojja")
    rith_msg.session_id = "008"
    with rith_sen:
        rith_sen.send_messages(rith_msg)
    servicebus_client.close()

Output:


Thnx for the example!
This function - would be triggered by an Azure Service Bus topic, right?
def http_trigger_topic(req: func.HttpRequest, message: func.Out[str]) -> func.HttpResponse:
Would that also work, to send a ServiceBusMessage using the SDK, with a HTTP-trigger? I tried it, but I get a 500 Error on AzureFunction execution, as soon as I import  from azure.servicebus. As I am new to Python Im not sure if I do something wrong.

It seems, that as soon as I add dependency from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage,
and deploy the function via func azure functionapp publish MYFUNCTIONNAME
then the Azure Function loses its triggers. They are not listed in Portal. There are bugs like https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/2440 reported about this.
The error says Azure Functions shows 1 function found but 0 loaded when deployed.
So using SDK dependencies seem to break the function deployment. Event if it the function was correctly deploying before.

You need to add azure-servicebus in requirements.txt file then only it will work. It is triggered by message in topic .

Adding azure-servicebus helped.
Dont understand why it did not work just by adding the same to a http trigger.

You need to add that and Glad it worked

The following combination I derived from Rithwik.
Requirements.txt
azure-functions
datetime
azure-servicebus

Function, which combines
@app.route(route="http_trigger") with
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
and servicebus
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
Function to send
import logging
import azure.functions as func
from datetime import datetime
import json
from azure.servicebus import ServiceBusClient, ServiceBusMessage
import os

app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

# vs output into queue for python
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python


TOPIC_NAME_A = "alfdevapi6topic" 
CONN_STRING = os.environ['ServiceBusConnection']
SESSION_ID = "008"


@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    myMessage = "Hi alf this is my message via the queue to you."

    jsn_message_envelope =  generateMessage(myMessage, SESSION_ID)
    logging.info(f"Will send envelope: {jsn_message_envelope}")

    servicebus_client = ServiceBusClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=CONN_STRING)
    rith_sen = servicebus_client.get_topic_sender(TOPIC_NAME_A)
    rith_msg = ServiceBusMessage(jsn_message_envelope)
    rith_msg.session_id = SESSION_ID
    with rith_sen:
        rith_sen.send_messages(rith_msg)
    servicebus_client.close()


    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
            status_code=200
    )


def generateMessage(myMessage, mySessionId):
    now = datetime.now()
    print("now =", now)
    logging.info(f"Time stamp: {now}")

    dt_string = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

    my_json_string = f"""
    {{
        "body": "{myMessage}",
        "customProperties": {{
            "timePublish": "{dt_string}",
        }},
        "brokerProperties": {{
            "SessionId": "{mySessionId}"
        }}
    }}
    """

    return my_json_string

